# Inner outline shader algorithm

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, hlsl

Ive been trying to create an inner outline shader with a growable thickness.

I tried several things.

1. Checking the surrounding pixels, if they are transparent then color the current pixel black (or chosen outline color). If I want to control the thickness of the outline, I need to check n pixels in each direction of the current pixel (north, south, east, west, northwest, northeast, and so on), where n is the desired thickness. I am having performance issues with this approach though.
2. Copy the image, and shrink it to control the outline thickness. What ever is outside the this smaller copy is colored black (outline color), and what ever is inside is set to the original image. This only works for basic shapes though, imagine a doughnut shaped image with a hollow center, shrinking the image will outline the outer ring but not the inner ring.
3. Same as (2), but instead of shrinking the copy, just blur the copy (to control thickness) and then trim any pixels whose alpha != 1. This has worked the best, but its not perfect for complex shapes. Some areas will have a thicker stroke than other, when I want it to be consistent.

What other algorithm could I try? What is the general approach, how does photoshop implement it? My first algorithm is the most accurate of the three, but I am unable to make it work for pixel shader 2 because of the loop it requires.

Comment: Could I get an explanation for the downvote so that I could at least improve my question?

Comment: Perhaps it isn't clear what you're asking for. It sounds like you're not happy with the results from the methods you've tried and would like an alternative (I'm not the downvoter).

Answer (score 0):

You could create another mesh that is the "hole" or "inside mesh". I.e. a mesh that is everywhere within the original mesh by the desired radius.

Then render that to the stencil buffer and after that render the original mesh with outline color if stencil bits are not set. [Like in the stencil outlining.](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Object_Outlining.shtml)

You would need a new "inside mesh" for each different "inner outline thickness, so "growable" is hard to achieve.